# Links in navigation bar display bunched together

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm working on a website with a horizontal navigation bar using an unordered list of links and the links keep displaying bunched together despite having set padding for them. How can I rectify this?

I'm working off a W3Schools tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp) and I've essentially copied what they've done in the horizontal navigation bar section.

I've tried setting padding for the list items instead of the links but it makes no difference.

```css
/* Navigation bar:*/

#topNavDiv {
 display: block;
 border-style: solid;
 background-color: black;
 overflow: auto;

}

#topNavList {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;

}

.topNavListItem {
 float: right;

}

.topNavListItem, a {
 position: relative;
 right: 50px;
 display: block;
 padding: 10;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 background-color: black;

}
```

```html
<div id="topNavDiv">
   <ul id="topNavList">
    <li><a href="#" class="topNavListItem ubuntuFont">search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="topNavListItem ubuntuFont">contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="topNavListItem ubuntuFont">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="topNavListItem ubuntuFont">tutorials</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="topNavListItem ubuntuFont">home</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You had a wrong padding value, should be `padding: 10px;` (with px)

```css
/* Navigation bar:*/

#topNavDiv {
 display: block;
 border-style: solid;
 background-color: black;
 overflow: auto;

}

#topNavList {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;

}

.topNavListItem {
 float: right;

}

.topNavListItem, a {
 position: relative;
 right: 50px;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 background-color: black;

}
```

```html
<div id="topNavDiv">
  <ul id="topNavList">
    <li><a href="#" class="topNavListItem ubuntuFont">search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="topNavListItem ubuntuFont">contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="topNavListItem ubuntuFont">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="topNavListItem ubuntuFont">tutorials</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="topNavListItem ubuntuFont">home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```